# Как подключить библиотеку vuejs из node_modules в gulp

Tags: vue.js, gulp

gulp файл

```
var gulp          = require('gulp'),
gutil         = require('gulp-util' ),
sass          = require('gulp-sass'),
browserSync   = require('browser-sync'),
concat        = require('gulp-concat'),
uglify        = require('gulp-uglify'),
cleancss      = require('gulp-clean-css'),
rename        = require('gulp-rename'),
cache         = require('gulp-cache'),
del           = require('del'),
autoprefixer  = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
notify        = require('gulp-notify'),
rsync         = require('gulp-rsync');
```

таск на обработку скриптов:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
return gulp.src([
    'app/libs/modernizr/modernizr.js',
    'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'app/libs/jquery/jquery-ui.js',
    'app/libs/waypoints/waypoints.min.js',
    'app/libs/drawsvg/drawfillsvg.min.js',
    'app/libs/owl/owl.carousel.js',
    'app/js/common.js'
    ])
.pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'))
.pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
});
```

как подключить библиотеку vuejs, чтобы она конкатенировалась и складывалась в итоговый script.min.js

Answer (score 1):

решил вопрос так:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
return gulp.src([
    'app/libs/modernizr/modernizr.js',
    'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'app/libs/jquery/jquery-ui.js',
    'app/libs/waypoints/waypoints.min.js',
    'app/libs/drawsvg/drawfillsvg.min.js',
    'app/libs/owl/owl.carousel.js',
    ***'node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js',***
    'app/js/common.js'
    ])
.pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'))
.pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
```

});